return diag elements of nxn matrix without using a for-loop
Imagine having an array of matrices (nxkxk), how would I return the diagonal entries while keeping the original shape without using a for-loop.
For example, without keeping the original shape we could do np.diagonal(array_of_matrices, axis1=1, axis2=2)
Obviously I could just do this and then reconstruct the original shape, but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way.
I have tried nothing and I'm all out of ideas. np.diag does not take axis arguments.

Do you want to mask the non diagonal values? The output should be (n, k, k)?

If by mask you mean that they should just be zero, then yes. Edit: yes

You might want to provide an explicit input/output example, for example: n = 2 ; k = 3 ; a = np.arange(1, n*k*k+1).reshape(n,k,k)

You can use broadcasting to multiply an eye matrix by your k x n x n shaped array to return only the diagonal elements.
import numpy as np

n = 4
k = 3
arr = np.arange(k * n * n).reshape(k, n, n)
diags = arr * np.eye(n)

Here are the elements:
arr
# returns:
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]],

       [[16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26, 27],
        [28, 29, 30, 31]],

       [[32, 33, 34, 35],
        [36, 37, 38, 39],
        [40, 41, 42, 43],
        [44, 45, 46, 47]]])

diags
# returns:
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  5.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0., 10.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., 15.]],

       [[16.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0., 21.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0., 26.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., 31.]],

       [[32.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0., 37.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0., 42.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0., 47.]]])


Nice one :) Combined with where: b = np.where(np.eye(k), a, 0)

Oh nice.  Let me check the timings.

Looks like broadcasting is faster for small arrays (30, 30, 10), but np.where is faster for large array (100, 100, 100)

Very nice (and obvious in hindsight) also, thanks

You can also consider a[:, ~np.eye(k, dtype=bool)] = 0 for in place modification

Assuming:
n = 2 ; k = 3
a = np.arange(1, n*k*k+1).reshape(n,k,k)

array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 7,  8,  9]],

       [[10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18]]])

You could use a mask to identify elements to mask:
idx = np.arange(k)

a[:, idx[:,None]!=idx] = 0

Or, for a new array:
idx = np.arange(k)

b = np.where(idx[:,None]==idx, a, 0)

Output:
array([[[ 1,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  5,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  9]],

       [[10,  0,  0],
        [ 0, 14,  0],
        [ 0,  0, 18]]])


Okay, this seems like a nice solution, thanks.

@Rutger you can combine it with Jame's approach, for instance b = np.where(np.eye(k), a, 0)

Best is to use einsum.
method 1(Best) :
import numpy as np

# Example array of matrices with shape (n, k, k)
array_of_matrices = np.array([
    [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
    [[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18]]
])
print(array_of_matrices)
"""
[
[[ 1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9]]

 [[10 11 12]
  [13 14 15]
  [16 17 18]]
]
"""
"""
Why ijj -> ij  ?

Since the second and third index (j) in the input (ijj) refer 
to the same axis (rows and columns), 
this summation captures the diagonal elements (where i == j).
"""
diagonals = np.einsum("ijj->ij", array_of_matrices)

print(diagonals.shape)  
"""
(2, 3)
"""

print(diagonals)
"""  
[[ 1  5  9]
 [10 14 18]]
"""

method 2 :
import numpy as np

array_of_matrices = np.array([
    [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
    [[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18]]
])
print(array_of_matrices )
"""
[[[ 1  2  3]
[ 4  5  6]
[ 7  8  9]]

[[10 11 12]
[13 14 15]
[16 17 18]]]
"""

"""
np.arange(k) creates an array like [0, 1, 2, ..., k-1].

This ensures we pick elements from the same row (i) and column (j) within each matrix.
Using the same array for both second and third-axis indexing allows us to choose entries
where i == j for each matrix, thereby extracting the diagonals.
np.arange(array_of_matrices.shape[1]) creates a sequence of indices that, 
when used for indexing along both the row and column dimensions,
ensures you pick elements that lie on the diagonal of each matrix within the array.
"""
diagonals = array_of_matrices[:, np.arange(array_of_matrices.shape[1]),
                               np.arange(array_of_matrices.shape[1])]

print(diagonals.shape)#(2, 3)  
print(diagonals)
"""
[[ 1  5  9]
[10 14 18]]
"""


 

